# Exception when converting JObject "ToObject"

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a Post function which recieves a JObject(Newtonsoft Json) as a post varible.

Now I need this to be a JObject since I have the "real type" based on other information and I need extra flexibilty(I cant use generics and other options).

Now I'm using this code:

```
JObject data; // this is assigned with the data from the post.
Type type = getTypeFromSomeWhere(param1);
object obj = data.ToObject(type); // I need this since I reflect the object later on.
```

My Input data looks like this:

```
{
  "Disclaimer": {},
  "Name": {
    "IsRelevant": true,
    "Value": "Sample Name"
  },
}
```

I'm trying to convert the object into this Type:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Disclaimer{ get; set; }

    public Field<string> Name{ get; set; } // Field has Value\IsRelevant and other stuff.
}
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
{"Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'Disclaimer'."}
```

I'm trying to understand why it happens. The object looks ok. I guess it's due to the empty object Disclaimer, but I need to support those situations.

**Edit:**
When I insert a string into the Disclaimer then everything works.
How can I tell him to insert "null" into empty objects?

Comment: Type of Disclaimer is string and you supply object that's why it gives exception

Comment: Yes, I exactly understood that and edited. How can I work the "empty objects" as nulls?

Comment: Do not pass anything. that will insert null value for Disclaimer

Comment: I'm so stupid..Someone changed something in my code which ruined this..Thanks for the answers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect. Disclaimer is an object since it's defined as `{}`.

```
{
  "Disclaimer": {},  //this is an OBJECT
  "Name": {  
    "IsRelevant": true,
    "Value": "Sample Name"
  },
}
```

That's why you get the error `{"Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'Disclaimer'."}` as JSON.NET finds the `{` and you are trying to map it to a string.

As for `Name` it's also an object. I don't know how your `Field<T>` looks like, but as long as it have a `Value` property it should work.

A correct model:

```
public class Disclaimer
{
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public string Disclaimer{ get; set; }
    public Field<string> Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm so stupid..Someone changed something in my code which ruined this..Thanks for the answer!!